# How do I remove suhosin?

Tags: phpmyadmin

In my PHPmyadmin I am seeing a warning message about Suhosin being installed, how can I remove this or disable it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suhosin is a PHP extension designed to protect your PHP installation, if you really want to disable it:

Edit `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` (as root) and add:

```
[suhosin]
suhosin.simulation = On
```

Then restart apache, `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: Doesn't work for recent packages anymore since suhosin is compiled in and not longer a module.
Thanks Ubuntu !!

Comment: This one works on Ubuntu 12.04 server. I have tried it recently. Was scratching my head in bewilderment on why the form can't go beyond 25 file uploads, and I know I set to max at 30 under php.ini. In the end, it was this patch that was the culprit. Adding the above under php.ini solved it. Thank you for this tip! :)

Comment: Could not disable it by those instructions with Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Answer (score 1):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove php5-suhosin
```